# changes of Firebase realtime database not visible in console

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm learning to use Firebases realtime database and stumbled upon an error. If I change data via set those changes aren't visible in the console of firebase but if i try to access the data I set via get everything is fine.

There`s where I want to see the changes
[image]

Here is the initialization code

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Here is the code for referencing, set and get

```dart
onPressed: () => {
          print("button"),
          FirebaseDatabase.instance
              .ref("/")
              .child("users")
              .set({"name": "test", "int": 875})
              .then((value) => print("set value"))
              .onError((error, stackTrace) => print("$error, $stackTrace")),
          FirebaseDatabase.instance
              .ref("/")
              .child("users")
              .get()
              .then((value) => print(value.value))
              .onError((error, stackTrace) => print("$error, $stackTrace")),
        },
```

Comment: Do you imagine what it will be with your browser if you will see all 200k users chatting ? Think now where do you see error.

Comment: I think you could open the developer function from your browser to make sure whether the value from Firebase realtime view has reloaded or not whilst you've done "Set" command. If the page doesn't reload again, it means you will not see the updated value. isn't it? And you've confirmed that value was changed after you read again from flutter.